# Software Breakpoints and Modern OOOE Processors

Tags: debugging, operating-system, cpu-architecture

I understand that modern operation systems provide api's for debugging. When a debugger process asks the kernel to set a breakpoint on machine code instruction of another process, the kernel replaces the first byte of the instruction with an opcode that causes an interrupt.

The interrupt handler would halt the process, save the registers and notify the debugging process.

What I do not understand is what exactly happens on out of order execution processors. The interrupt instruction could be executed before it's predecessors or after it's ancestors and thus, at the time of the interrupt, the registers and memory will contain wrong values.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier seems related

Comment: 'the kernel replaces the first byte of the instruction with an opcode that causes an interrupt' - no, not today.  Modern processors have debug hardware built-in to allow debugger interrupts on various conditions, eg. an instruction-pointer match with a breakpoint register.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is why all the ordered events such as interrupts, faults, exceptions, etc, are always handled at the commit point in out-of-order processors, where the original program order is restored and the correct machine state can be captured. This means that you may know of a pending event but still delay handling it.

Note that actions visible by the external world such as stores to memory are also handled past this stage, so you can never view the speculative internal state of an out-of-order core (well, except for side channel attack methods...), and any interrupt or breakpoint will also be ordered correctly with regards to them

Comment: Asynchronous events (relative to the instruction flow), usually called interrupts, can choose a commit point. Furthermore, synchronous event handling could begin (speculatively) before commitment. Of course, so far no one (AFAIK) has considered the benefit worth the complexity! (Such nuances might just confuse someone looking for an answer to the question.) Saying that modern processors (both OoO and in-order issue/OoO completion) provide *precise exceptions* would give the OP a term to use for further research. Likewise distinguishing *architectural* state (e.g., register and memory values)

Comment: from *non-architectural* state and effects (e.g., power use, DRAM accesses, cache contents) might be more 'technically correct' than "actions visible by the external world" but **less clear to the target audience**. Not burying people with a display of one's erudition is generally a virtue! +1

Comment: @PaulA.Clayton - Good point about precise exceptions, but architectural vs. non-architectural wasn't the point I was making - a DRAM write access (which I would define as architectural as the memory is part of the system architectural state) is much more problematic than an internal register write (which is obviously architectural, but very simple to hide from external inspection and roll back when required to expose). Hence the distinction is between externally visible effects that must not be performed speculatively, and internal effects that can be speculated freely.

Comment: By the way, you're also correct about asynchronous events, but he asked about breakpoints/traps (and i'd add sw level interrupts) that require higher precision.

Comment: Quibble: a register write is not necessarily architectural (as opposed to microarchitectural); sadly, "architecture" is overloaded, sometimes meaning microarchitecture/organization (e.g., "the Nehalem architecture"), sometimes meaning Architecture/ISA (i.e., ISA proper and other interface guarantees like memory ordering), and sometimes meaning something broader ("computer architecture"). (I should probably resist the temptation to be so chatty!)